# TYPO3 Update: cannot find deprecated RTE properties

Tags: typo3, deprecated, updates, typoscript, rte

I want to update from TYPO3 4.7.5 to TYPO3 4.7.10. Now I'm in the `Upgrade Wizard` and it says:

> Deprecated RTE properties in Page TSconfig
>
> The following Page TSconfig RTE properties are deprecated since TYPO3 4.6 and will be
>   removed in TYPO3 6.0.
>
> Deprecated property   Use instead
>   disableRightClick contextMenu.disable
>   disableContextMenu    contextMenu.disable
>   hidePStyleItems   buttons.formatblock.removeItems
>   hideFontFaces buttons.fontstyle.removeItems
>   fontFace  buttons.fontstyle.addItems
>   hideFontSizes buttons.fontsize.removeItems
>   classesCharacter  buttons.textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses
>   classesParagraph  buttons.blockstyle.tags.div.allowedClasses
>   classesTable  buttons.blockstyle.tags.table.allowedClasses
>   classesTD buttons.blockstyle.tags.td.allowedClasses
>   classesImage  buttons.image.properties.class.allowedClasses
>   classesLinks  buttons.link.properties.class.allowedClasses
>   blindImageOptions buttons.image.options.removeItems
>   blindLinkOptions  buttons.link.options.removeItems
>   defaultLinkTarget buttons.link.properties.target.default
>   fontSize  buttons.fontsize.addItems
>   RTE.default.classesAnchor RTE.default.buttons.link.properties.class.allowedClasses
>   RTE.default.classesAnchor.default.[link-type] RTE.default.buttons.link.[link-type].properties.class.default
>   mainStyleOverride contentCSS   mainStyleOverride_add.[key]    contentCSS 
>   mainStyle_font    contentCSS   mainStyle_size contentCSS
>   mainStyle_color   contentCSS   mainStyle_bgcolor  contentCSS
>   inlineStyle.[any-keystring]   contentCSS   ignoreMainStyleOverride    n.a. 
>   disableTYPO3Browsers  buttons.image.TYPO3Browser.disabled and
>   buttons.link.TYPO3Browser.disabled
>   showTagFreeClasses    buttons.blockstyle.showTagFreeClasses and
>   buttons.textstyle.showTagFreeClasses
>   disablePCexamples buttons.blockstyle.disableStyleOnOptionLabel and
>   buttons.textstyle.disableStyleOnOptionLabel   You are currently using
>   some of these properties on 1 pages (including deleted and hidden
>   pages).
>
> Pages id's: 2
>
> This wizard cannot update the following properties, some of which are present on those pages:
>
> Deprecated property
>   fontSize
>   RTE.default.classesAnchor
>   RTE.default.classesAnchor.default.[link-type]
>   mainStyleOverride
>   mainStyleOverride_add.[key]
>   mainStyle_font
>   mainStyle_size
>   mainStyle_color
>   mainStyle_bgcolor
>   inlineStyle.[any-keystring]
>   ignoreMainStyleOverride
>   disableTYPO3Browsers
>   showTagFreeClasses
>   disablePCexamples
>
> Therefore, the Page TSconfig column of those pages will need to be updated manually.
>
> Only page records were searched for deprecated properties. However, such properties can also be used in BE group and BE user records (prepended with page.). These are not searched nor updated by this wizard.
>
> Page TSconfig may also be included from external files. These are not updated by this wizard. If required, the update will need to be done manually.
>
> Note also that deprecated properties have been replaced in default configurations provided by htmlArea RTE

I found a page TS config:

```
RTE.classes{
  highlight{
      name = newStyle
      value = color:#636466; font-size:15px;
  } 
  brown{
      name = braun
      value = color:#9A3811;
  }
}

RTE.default{
  ignoreMainStyleOverride = 1 
  useCSS = 1
  showTagFreeClasses = 1
  contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte.css
  buttons {
    blockstyle.tags.div.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight, brown)
    blockstyle.tags.p.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight, brown)
    textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight, brown)
  }
  proc.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight, brown)
}
```

I changed it to

```
RTE.classes{
  highlight{
      name = newStyle
      value = color:#636466; font-size:15px;
  } 
  brown{
      name = braun
      value = color:#9A3811;
  }
}

RTE.default{
  useCSS = 1
  contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte.css
  buttons {
    blockstyle.showTagFreeClasses = 1
    blockstyle.tags.div.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight, brown)
    blockstyle.tags.p.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight, brown)
    textstyle.showTagFreeClasses = 1
    textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight, brown)
  }
  proc.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight, brown)
}
```

but the `Upgrade Wizard` still complains. I looked in the main TS, user TS, user group TS, export of the database but there is none of the mentioned properties used. My added style also doesn't work anymore ...

Where are the deprecated properties? How can I find that out?

Comment: Maybe some TypoScript code has been sourced out (i.e. somewhere in fileadmin/); or the deprecated properties are used within an extension (typo3conf/ext/)?

Comment: @Mateng: No there is nothing sourced out, but an extension could be the problem. What I don't get is that it shows me the page id where it should be (but there is nothing). Do you know why my defined RTE class is not working anymore?

Comment: Have you ever made progress on this issue @testing?

Comment: @Huelfe: Sorry, can't remember what I've done anymore ...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do a manual search in the database pages table to find pages with TSconfig:

```
SELECT uid, TSconfig FROM pages WHERE TSconfig!='';
```

If this will not give you a desired result, then grep for settings in your extensions:

```
find typo3conf/ext/ -type f -name ext_*\.php -exec egrep -H -n '(addPageTSConfig|addUserTSConfig)' {} \;
```

The TSconfig deprecation handling for RTE is done in:
`tx_rtehtmlarea_deprecatedRteProperties::getPagesWithDeprecatedRteProperties()`

This class can be found in `typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/hooks/install/class.tx_rtehtmlarea_deprecatedrteproperties.php`

Comment: I will try it the next time. What I have done is to export the database to a SQL file and searched in it - without success ..

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade wizard is using SQL statement

```
SELECT uid, TSconfig FROM pages WHERE (TSConfig LIKE BINARY "%RTE.%showTagFreeClasses%" AND TSConfig NOT LIKE BINARY "%RTE.%showTagFreeClassess%")
```

so even changing showTagFreeClasses to buttons.blockstyle.showTagFreeClasses doesn't help. Just remove from RTE configuration and all is fine.